# Get Balance of Sol account more then one account

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, jsonrpc-api, balance, solscan

Can be any API or method to get the balance of a Sol account (more than one account in one time ) not use loop like getBalance() not that function,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wallets are just Accounts too, you can use getMultiple to fetch multiple accounts and read the lamports if you just want the SOL balance:

```
connection.getMultipleAccountsInfo(publicKeys).then(accountsInfo => {
  const balances = accountsInfo.map(accountInfo => {
    if (accountInfo === null) { return null };
    return accountInfo.lamports / LAMPORTS_PER_SOL; 
  });
```